# What is the relationship between strict convex combination and convex hull of a set?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

Let $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n $ where $i=1,...,l$ and  $1\leq l \leq n$. Also, let 
$$
W = \{y = \sum_1^l \alpha_i x_i \mid \alpha_i > 0 \sum_1^l \alpha_i =1 \}
$$ be the set of all strict convex combination of $x_i$'s.

We know that the following 
$$
U = \{y = \sum_1^l \alpha_i x_i \mid \alpha_i \geq 0 \sum_1^l \alpha_i =1 \}
$$ is the convex hull of the set $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{l}$.

What is the closure of $W$, i.e. $cl(W)$? Can we just say if we relax strictly greater than zero of $\alpha_i$ in $W$ we can get its closure? 
Please give a counter example if it is not true or prove it if it is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum \alpha_i x_i$ is the limit of $\sum \alpha_i^{k} x_i$  as $k \to \infty$ where $\alpha_i^{k}= 
(\alpha_i+\frac 1 k)/( \sum_j( \alpha_j+\frac 1 k))$ so $U$ is the closure of $W$.

Comment: We are talking about finite dimension $(n)$, $n$ is a finite number. How would that possible to let $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: Replace $n$ above by $k$. Unfortunate collision of variables...

Comment: @Saeed Sorry about the typo. Answer edited.

Comment: @copper.hat: Why such a choice for $\alpha_i^k$ is the case?

Comment: The multipliers are strict.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: How did you come up with this ratio? Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: @copper.hat: I cannot understand. We define $\alpha_i^k$ to get $\alpha_i$ as its limit. We could have written $\alpha_i^k= \alpha_i +1/k$, and have the the same answer. What is the role of denominator?

Comment: The multipliers must sum to one

Comment: @copper.hat: Sorry for having the same notation for multipliers. Could you tell me $\alpha_i$ is the one corresponding $W$ or $U$?

Comment: @Saeed I am starting with an element of $U$ and showing that it is a limit of a sequence from $W$.